# Excluding triples based on substring

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a graph created by sponging web pages. I'm trying to write a query to exclude all triples where the subject is a web page. I can get these triples simply by

`FILTER (STRENDS((STR(?i)), "html"))`

but what's the best way to exclude them. Basically I need all {?s ?p ?o} minus the subset {?i ?p ?o}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
SELECT *
{ ?s ?p ?o 
  FILTER ( ! STRENDS( STR(?s), "html") )
}
```

filters the outcome the pattern.